# My loop creating another parent array rather than appending it to where I have pointed?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to loop through my database and be able to group between day, time, class, and students. I have been able to use a bunch of `if(!isset())` statements to achieve what I am after with this code.

```
foreach ($sqlEx as $rows) {
    if(!isset($day) || $day !== $rows['DAY']) {
        $day = $rows['DAY'];
        $scheduleJSON['DAY'] = $day;
    }
    if(!isset($time) || $time !== $rows['CLASSTIME']) {
        $time = $rows['CLASSTIME'];
        $scheduleJSON[$time]= [];
        $scheduleJSON[NULL] = $scheduleJSON[$time];
        unset($scheduleJSON[NULL]);
    }
    if(!isset($instructor) || $instructor !== $rows['INSTRUCTOR']) {
        $instructor = $rows['INSTRUCTOR'];
        $classlevel = $rows['CLASSLEVEL'];
        $maxstudent = $rows['MAXSTUDENT'];
        $scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES'][]['CLASS'] = ['INSTRUCTOR' => $instructor, 'CLASS LEVEL' => $classlevel, 'MAX STUDENTS' => $maxstudent];
    } else {
        $studentfirst = $rows['STUDENTFIRST'];
        $studentlast = $rows['STUDENTLAST'];
        $scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES']['CLASS']['STUDENTS'][] = ['STUDENT' => ['FIRST NAME' => $studentfirst, 'LAST NAME' => $studentlast]];
    }
}
```

I am looking at getting my array to have this structure:

```
$scheduleJSON = [
    'DAY' => NULL, 'TIME' => [
        'CLASSES' => [
            'CLASS' => [
                'INSTRUCTOR' => NULL, 'CLASS LEVEL' => NULL, 'MAX STUDENTS' => NULL, 'STUDENTS' => [
                    'STUDENT' => [
                        'FIRST NAME' => NULL, 'LAST NAME' => NULL, 'DATE OF BIRTH' => NULL, 'PARENT FIRST NAME' => NULL, 'PARENT LAST NAME' => NULL
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

However, when I print to JSON encode, my problem, I think, is within my `else` statement. Instead of appending the **STUDENTS** as another `key => value` in the class after `MAX STUDENTS`, it's creating another `CLASS` array.

```
"DAY": "THURSDAY",
"530": {
    "CLASSES": {
        "0": {
            "CLASS": {
                "INSTRUCTOR": "Teacher",
                "CLASS LEVEL": "JUNIOR",
                "MAX STUDENTS": "8"
            }
        },
        "CLASS": {
            "STUDENTS": [
                {
                    "STUDENT": {
                        "FIRST NAME": "Student",
                        "LAST NAME": ""
                    }
                },
```

Any help at this point would be greatly appreciated - I have been searching the problem and answer for days.

-- EDIT
Array from $sqlEx. Please note that I have removed the name data that did come out with it for privacy.

```
array(20) {
  ["DAY"]=>
  string(8) "THURSDAY"
  [0]=>
  string(8) "THURSDAY"
  ["CLASSTIME"]=>
  string(3) "530"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "530"
  ["CLASSLEVEL"]=>
  string(6) "JUNIOR"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "JUNIOR"
  ["MAXSTUDENT"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["INSTRUCTOR"]=>
  string(4) "TEACHER"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "TEACHER"
  ["STUDENTFIRST"]=>
  string(5) "First Name"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "First Name"
  ["STUDENTLAST"]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["STUDENTDOB"]=>
  string(10) "2007-04-28"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "2007-04-28"
  ["PARENTFIRST"]=>
  string(12) "Parent First Name"
  [8]=>
  string(12) "Parent First Name"
  ["PARENTLAST"]=>
  string(6) "Parent Last Name"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "Parent Last Name"
}
```

Comment: is it `$scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES'][]['CLASS']` vs `$scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES']['CLASS']['STUDENTS'][]` ? I think you should be using some kind of ClassID for your array index selections.

Comment: please provide array you getting from $sqlEx

Comment: `$scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES'][]['CLASS']` is to add a new class/lesson in the array everytime the instructor changes in the database whereas `$scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES']['CLASS']['STUDENTS'][]` is to add a new student to that class.

Comment: Hi @GyandeepSharma , updating my questions for you now.

Comment: Please give result you get from echo "<pre>";print_r($sqlEx );die; put  this line before foreach loop. Your array is confusing. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Gyandeep, I have done so however it is just my SQL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when adding `INSTRUCTOR` key, you have to remove the `[]` between `['CLASSES']` and `['CLASS']`

```
$scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES']['CLASS'] = ['INSTRUCTOR' => $instructor, 'CLASS LEVEL' => $classlevel, 'MAX STUDENTS' => $maxstudent];
```

Next, move everything inside the else condition outside. Basically removing the else condition.

```
if(!isset($instructor) || $instructor !== $rows['INSTRUCTOR']) {
    // instructor codes
} // else is removed
$studentfirst = $rows['STUDENTFIRST'];
$studentlast = $rows['STUDENTLAST'];
$scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES']['CLASS']['STUDENTS'][] = ['STUDENT' => ['FIRST NAME' => $studentfirst, 'LAST NAME' => $studentlast]];
```

This will work effeciently assuming each data for STUDENTFIRST up to PARENTLAST are unique. No duplicate student info. Otherwise, you need to have something to check if student already exist.

**Note**: I suggested removing else condition because it will not cover the first loop. Thus, the student's info for the first row won't be added to the $scheduledJSON.
If you need the else condition, you have to add the STUDENT's info on the $instructor's IF condition

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for your reply. It has worked very efficiently, however, now I have the problem that multiple classes for a specific timeslot are not showing (only the first class). Is this because we removed the `[]` from between `CLASSES` and `CLASS`?

Comment: @user3436334 Sorry, I didn't take having more than 1 CLASS into account. Does the CLASS depends on INSTRUCTOR?

Comment: All good. For the most part, yes. There are occasions where there could be two or three classes with the same teacher at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm. If it's possible to have the same teacher for different classes, then we can't use the instructor to filter the classes. Is there something like, class A, class B... or something unique about classes so we can separate them?

Comment: That would be the class levels. Never am I going to have an instructor with 2 of the same levels at the same time.

Comment: Hi @Erwin, I have been going through the database more thoroughly (unfortunately I didn't build it), and we have unique CLASS ids. This I think will be the best thing to separate them.

Comment: The CLASSLEVEL like JUNIOR on your array example? If so, that would actually make this easier to fix. After setting CLASSTIME, you need another condition to check if CLASSLEVEL already exist for that classtime. Then add CLASS then proceed to adding Instructor and Student's info. So, I suggest, instead of `['CLASSES']['CLASS']` make it like `['CLASSES']['JUNIOR']`

Comment: By George I've got it! I'll post my final solution. Thank you so much for your help Erwin. I decided to use the class id's as the unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

So after working through the issue with @Erwin, I have finally been able to output the JSON as follows:

```
{
"DAY": "THURSDAY",
"530": {
    "CLASSES": {
        "CLASS-1335": {
            "INSTRUCTOR": "TEACHER",
            "CLASS LEVEL": "JUNIOR",
            "MAX STUDENTS": "8",
            "START TIME": "530",
            "FINISH TIME": "730",
            "STUDENTS": [
                {
                    "STUDENT": {
                        "FIRST NAME": "First Name",
                        "LAST NAME": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "CLASS-2243": {
            "INSTRUCTOR": "TEACHER",
            "CLASS LEVEL": "SENIOR ",
            "MAX STUDENTS": "8",
            "START TIME": "530",
            "FINISH TIME": "730",
            "STUDENTS": [
                {
                    "STUDENT": {
                        "FIRST NAME": "First Name",
                        "LAST NAME": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "STUDENT": {
                        "FIRST NAME": "First Name",
                        "LAST NAME": ""
                    }
                }, ETC...
```

The following is the code that allowed me to accomplish this. I needed to add some more logic into my code to pull a unique identifier for each class (such as CLASS.ID) rather than just blindly adding a new level to the array.

So for each level of this multidimensional array, an `if(!isset($var) || $var !== $rows[$val]) {}` was needed (in order of parent to child) to discern if the current record being processed had the same property (such as DAY or CLASS TIME) - if the value in any of the statements was different (or not set), set the new variable value and push it into the array.

```
foreach ($sqlEx as $rows) {
        if(!isset($day) || $day !== $rows['DAY']) {
            $day = $rows['DAY'];
            $scheduleJSON['DAY'] = $day;
        }
        if(!isset($time) || $time !== $rows['CLASSTIME']) {
            $time = $rows['CLASSTIME'];
            $scheduleJSON[$time]= [];
            $scheduleJSON[NULL] = $scheduleJSON[$time];
            unset($scheduleJSON[NULL]);
        }
        if(!isset($classid) || $classid !== $rows['CLASSID']) {
            $classid = $rows['CLASSID'];
            $instructor = $rows['INSTRUCTOR'];
            $classlevel = $rows['CLASSLEVEL'];
            $maxstudent = $rows['MAXSTUDENT'];
            $finishtime = $rows['CLASSENDTIME'];
            $scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES']['CLASS' . '-' . $classid] = [
                'INSTRUCTOR' => $instructor,
                'CLASS LEVEL' => $classlevel,
                'MAX STUDENTS' => $maxstudent,
                'START TIME' => $time,
                'FINISH TIME' => $finishtime
            ];
        }

        $studentfirst = $rows['STUDENTFIRST'];
        $studentlast = $rows['STUDENTLAST'];
        $scheduleJSON[$time]['CLASSES']['CLASS' . '-' . $classid]['STUDENTS'][] = [
            'STUDENT' => [
                'FIRST NAME' => $studentfirst,
                'LAST NAME' => $studentlast
            ]
        ];
    }

    print_r(json_encode($scheduleJSON, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

This is a decent chunk of code although I am not sure it can be refactored or not, however, it works quite fast and well for my situation - which is creating a grouped list for a class schedule.

Thanks everyone for your help! I have definitely grown from this!

Regards
Michael Z

Comment: Thank you. :) Now to do recursion through to create nested divs with appropriate classes... ugh...